# How to Create a Form with Ajax Output External to the Form?

Tags: forms, ajax

What I want to achieve is:

1. A form with a number of selects / textfields
2. A div external to the form that contains information pertinent to the form's current input (i.e. not contained in the form element)
3. Updating of the external div when the form input changes

The scenario is makes and models for part 1, products available for part 2. The important part is that the product list output is not contained in the form because the add to cart ajax functionality of the parts fail if inside the form itself (I haven't found an answer for that one either).

I've implemented this with hook_entity_extra_field_info() which ultimately returns

```
\Drupal::formBuilder() -> getForm('Drupal\my_module\Form\PartProductsForm', $tid)
```

Everything in the form works well but I really have no idea how to get the product list into the external div. Well actually, I have managed it but it seems like a really bad way to do it!

I'm not sure there's much point pasting my code here as it's not achieving what I want. Almost certainly plenty of bad practices in there too (my first D8 module) but FWIW, here's the code for displaying the form:

```
      // Get the term ID
  $tid = $entity -> get('tid') -> value;      
  // Pass the parameter to the form
  $form['form'] = \Drupal::formBuilder() -> getForm('Drupal\p4b_mods\Form\PartProductsForm', $tid);
  // Create the content too
  $form['parts_list'] = \Drupal::formBuilder() -> getForm('Drupal\p4b_mods\Form\PartProductsForm', $tid, true)['part_products'];
  $build = $form;
```

And the form with the current hacky code:

```
class PartProductsForm extends FormBase {
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'part_products_form';
  }

  protected $termStorage;
  protected $tid = 0;
  protected $manufacturer = 0;
  protected $model = 0;

  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager) {
    $this -> termStorage = $entity_type_manager -> getStorage('taxonomy_term');
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('entity_type.manager')
    );
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $tid = NULL, $dataOnly = false) {
    if ($this -> tid == 0) $this -> tid = $tid;
    if ($dataOnly == true) return $this -> buildFormData();

// Functionality for changing the manufacturer/model
$element = $form_state -> getTriggeringElement();
if ($element != NULL) {
  // What changed?
  switch ($element['#title']) {
    case 'Manufacturer':

      // ...etc

  }
}

// Add the manufacturer text box, use autocomplete
$form['manufacturer'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'Manufacturer',
  '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'my_module.autocomplete.manufacturer',
  '#ajax' => [
    'event' => 'autocompleteclose',
    'callback' => [$this, 'updateManufacturer'],
    'wrapper' => 'model-select',
    'disable_refocus' => true,
  ],
];

// Ajax div so we can ajax in the model
$form['model_div'] = [
  '#type' => 'html_tag',
  '#tag' => 'div',
  '#attributes' => [
    'id' => ['model-select'],
  ],
];

// Add the model autocomplete, pass the manufacturer ID in the autocomplete so it only returns models
// for the current manufacturer
$form['model_div']['model'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'Model',
  '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'my_module.autocomplete.model',
  '#autocomplete_route_parameters' => [
    'manufacturerId' => $this -> manufacturer,
  ],
  '#ajax' => [
    'event' => 'autocompleteclose',
    'callback' => [$this, 'updateModel'],
    'wrapper' => 'year-select',
    'disable_refocus' => true,
  ],
];

    return $form;
  }


/* Build the renderable array of the parts list for the term */
  public function buildFormData() {
    // Placeholder for the products 
    $renderArray['part_products'] = [
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'div',
      '#attributes' => [
        'id' => ['part-products-data'],
      ],
    ];    
    // Now we've got our filters, get the list of actual products that match
    $connection = \Drupal::database();

    // Query the database 
    $query = $connection -> select('commerce_product', 'product');

    // ...etc...

    $result = $query -> distinct() -> execute();
    foreach ($result as $record) {
      // Load the commerce product 
      $entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager() -> getStorage('commerce_product') -> load($record -> product_id);
      // Get the view builder for the entity
      $viewBuilder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager() -> getViewBuilder('commerce_product');
      // Get the list view
      $preRender = $viewBuilder -> view($entity, 'list');
      // Add to the form
      $renderArray['part_products'][$record -> product_id] = $preRender;
    }
    return $renderArray;

  }

  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }

  public function updateManufacturer(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $form['model_div']['model']['#value'] = '- All -';
    $this -> addSectionResponse($response, $form['model_div'], '#model-select');
    $formData = $this -> buildFormData();
    $this -> addSectionResponse($response, $formData, '#part-products-data');
    return $response;
  }

  public function updateModel(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $formData = $this -> buildFormData();
    $this -> addSectionResponse($response, $formData, '#part-products-data');
    return $response;    
  }


  private function addSectionResponse(AjaxResponse $response, array $formSection, $selector) {
    $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
    $rendered = $renderer -> render($formSection);
    $data = BubbleableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($formSection);
    $attachments = $data -> getAttachments();
    $response -> addAttachments($attachments);  
    $response -> addCommand(new ReplaceCommand($selector, $rendered));
  }
}
```

Comment: You can create custom #ajax commands, that will insert the content into the DIV you specify: https://weknowinc.com/blog/creating-custom-ajax-command-drupal-8

Comment: Yes, I did/do that however when the form is first loaded the DIV does not have the content, it won't until the first AJAX call. I saw a couple of possilbilities:
1. Fire one of the AJAX events when the form is built
2. Obtain the content from the form for the DIV somehow. I managed to do this by passing an additional parameter to buildForm and calling formBuilder() -> getForm twice. That seems very hacky to me.

Comment: If you want to populate the DIV on page load, then you'll need to create a JS script, attach it to the form, and set it up to populate the DIV on page load.

Comment: Thanks @Jaypan, I'll give that a go.

Comment: Worked a treat triggering autocompleteclose on the manufacturer text field. Thanks @Jaypan!

Comment: Great ........ :)